# Why has my Computer Bluescreened 4 times in the last 5 days

Tags: windows, windows-10, motherboard

After calling MSI regarding my mobo. They claimed the issues I was having was due to a windows update. I'm skeptical this is true. But after installing Bluescreenview this is what i've been getting.

[image]

[image]

He had me uninstall the most recent windows Feature update. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Windbg. I'm not sure if this is what you're after.

Entire log of 1 dmp file: https://justpaste.it/47xgy

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling TCP offloading?

Comment: BlueScreenView is notorious for reporting the incorrect reason.  The only true reliable way is to use WinDBG.  **Any additional information should be submitted as an edit to your question instead of a comment.**  Your last image in your comment is inaccessible.

Comment: @ramhound updated the question for you.